# Completely remove windows 8.1 taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-8, taskbar, media-center

Does anyone know of a way to completely remove the taskbar in windows 8? I have tried taskbar eliminator as suggested in a different post however it doesn't work reliably in windows 8. I'm using this windows 8 installation for media center purposes and so the taskbar is really getting in the way, any ideas? I don't mind having to do some registry changes if that's what's necessary. Thanks!

Comment: activate the option to autohide the taskbar (this is part of Windows since Win95).

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with this issue for a couple years now. I'm not sure how to eliminate the taskbar programatically- though of course it *can* be done, as evinced below- but I know of a couple  convoluted solutions:

- StarDock's "ObjectDock" software: you can pick up a free trial by Googling it. If you set it to start on system startup, make the dock transparent, remove all the icons, and use an empty .ico file as a placeholder (it needs at least one shortcut present, or else it populates the dock itself), this will take care of your taskbar completely in an unobtrusive way (once you go through the trouble of setting it up, that is.) Also, the trial doesn't seem to expire if used in exactly this manner, though you'll get popups nagging you to purchase, which I finally did.
- "Dexpot": Dexpot also has a 'remove the taskbar' function, if virtual desktops are your thing. To enable it, install Dexpot, right click on the tray icon, select "configure desktops," go into 'tools' for your particular desktop, and tick "taskbar." This beats the native Windows 'hide the taskbar' feature, but isn't quite as seamless as ObjectDock.

That's the best I've been able to come up with. If I'm able to figure out how to do this with a script, or via the registry, I'll edit my answer and link to the script/registry change.

Answer (score -1):

you can do so directly by editing the registry entry of the task manager.

Enter the registry by typing `regedit` in the run command.
and then locate the following:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify

Delete the following entries -

> iconstreams & pasticonstreams

After deleting the registry entries you must ctrl+alt+del to bring up Task Manager, then End Task for "explorer.exe"

The taskbar will then disappear, ctrl+alt+del again and "Start New Task" and type "explorer.exe"

Comment: This just disables the Windows 8 notifications; it does not remove the taskbar.